# Is it possible to get the current height offset inside the div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div with the height of 500px. This is the main div, inside this div I want to know the position offset of the current line/div/html element inside that div.

Let me explain this with a picture:

[image]

Suppose I am in Div 2. Can I know at how many pixels offset content at any point inside this div lies?

Here is my example markup:

```
<div class="main" style='height:500px'>

    <div id="div1">
    </div>
    <div id="div2">
    </div>
    <div id="div3">
    </div>

</div>
```

Edit:

All the divs inside the main div have variable height due to dynamic content in them.

Comment: Did you try `.position()`.

Answer (score 1):

To know the **offset** value relative to the container you can use [`position()`](https://api.jquery.com/position/):

> It's important you set the parent with position:relative

```js
console.log($('#div2').position())
console.log($('#div2').offset())
```

```css
.main {background:purple;margin:30px;position:relative}
#div1 {height:150px;}
#div2 {height:3px;background:yellow}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main" style='height:500px'>
    <div id="div1">
    </div>
    <div id="div2">
    </div>
    <div id="div3">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jQuery position()](https://api.jqueryui.com/position/) method which will return and object containing the position of an element relative to another.

```js
var position = $('#div2').position();
console.log(position);
```

```css
#main{
    position: absolute;
}
#div1,
#div2,
#div3 {
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  width: 500px;
}


   #div1 {
  top: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#div2 {
  top: 75px;
  background-color: green;
}

#div3 {
  top: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main" style='height:500px; background-color:red;'>

  <div id="div1">
  </div>
  <div id="div2">
  </div>
  <div id="div3">
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [`.position()`](https://api.jquery.com/position/) function from jQuery. It will not account for hidden elements though.

```js
alert($("#four").position().top);
```

```css
#one {
  background-color: lightblue
}
#two {
  background-color: red
}
#three {
  background-color: lightgreen
}
#four {
  background-color: lightgreen
}
#five {
  background-color: lightgreen
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="one">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </div>
  <div id="two">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.

    <div id="three">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </div>
    <div id="four">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </div>
    <div id="five">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

> This solution will allow you check the relative height without setting
>   position:relative on the container.

jQuery provides a function called offset() that allows you to see the x & y position of any element relative to top left corner of the screen(x:0, y:0).  To determine the height of the element relative to its container you can subtract the container y coordinate from the element y coordinate.

```js
var div_one_top = $("#div1").offset().top
var div_main_top = $("div.main").offset().top
var div_one_to_main_top = div_one_top - div_main_top

$("#div1").text("#Div1 top relatative to the DOCUMENT: " + div_one_top)
$("#div2").text(".main top relatative to the DOCUMENT: " + div_main_top)
$("#div3").text("#Div1 top relatative to the div.main: " + div_one_to_main_top)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main" style='height:500px; padding:20px; position:absolute; left:22px; top: 45px'>

    <div id="div1">
    </div>
    <div id="div2">
    </div>
    <div id="div3">
    </div>

</div>
```